# String to List<List<dynamic>> - Error: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<List<dynamic>>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a 2d-List with a String and a Map inside like this:

```
List<List<dynamic>> content = 
[
  [
    "String",
    {
        "one": 23,
        "two: "two"
    }
  ],
];
```

To store this as a string locally I use json.encode(content).

But when I want to use

`json.decode("[["String",{"one": 23,"two: "two"}],]")`

to make this a variable of the type `List<List<dynamic>` I get the error:

`type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<List<dynamic>>'`

How do I solve this?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. I don't really understand why but this works.

```
content = List.from(json.decode("[["String",{"one": 23,"two: "two"}],]"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `List</*here*/>` an object what type the List should be. Your list should look like this: `List<List<Dynamic>>`. Class name instead of it's instance.

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to say.

Comment: Sorry my mistake in comment. I mean that while writing the answer I was sure that it's question about Java.